# I uninstalled Ariya in Kubuntu, how do I install it again?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, login-screen

I have installed Kubuntu 12.04 LTS. By mistake, I removed default login screen (Ariya).
It is now showing this message:

> Cannot login /user/shared/kde4/apps/kdm/themes/ariya

Now I am not able to login to previous GUI. It is getting login in command line.

How to resolve problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ mkdir kdm && cd kdm
$ sudo apt-get source kdm
```

And in the unpacked package folder you will find KDM with the Ariya files included.

**Here goes nothing** (aka. the apt-file utility):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkiMd.jpg]

You can find contents in packages with "apt-file". It's an application, you have to install it. Then run the `apt-file update` command as a single user. And then, you can search.
With: `apt-file find ariya`

**Another way if this one fails** (the almighty --reinstall flag):
Just use the `--reinstall` flag with apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kdm
```

Comment: (Do all this from terminal. Switch with "CTRL+ALT+F2" for example. Log in as you would do from the GUI. If you are in trouble with file management, use "mc" (sudo apt-get install mc) to copy the files. It's a gui file manager for the terminal. It uses ncurses.)

Comment: in KDM both ".tar.gz" and "tar.xz" files I have to extract?

Comment: I am not able to find Ariya...

Comment: The dget command does the unpack for you.

Comment: @green7: CTRL+ALT+T gives you the normal gui terminal. He can't login. So he can't bring up that either.

Comment: Ariya is not present in any of unpacked folder... can i use command like "sudo apt-get install kde-full"

Comment: it is showing following problem after booting....."cannot open theme file /usr/share/kde4/apps/kdm/themes/ariya"....so when i click on ok.... it shows "ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS ttyl  ubuntu login:_   " & when i enter username & password ,terminal window comes instead of showing kubuntu desktop icon window.....

Answer (score 0):

**Translation**

I had removed the theme and ariya Atela not carrying the login graphic then appeared a msg like this: Not found the theme `/user/shared/kde4/apps/kdm/themes/ariya` ok and I gave then carried in order to make the text login with the command entered here and it worked again loaded the login graphic follows the command that worked for me here

```
sudo apt-get install - reinstall kdm
```

command executed in text mode and after that I gave the command `shutdown-r now`

restarted the pc back when the logon screen graphically thanks for the tip.

---

Eu tinha removido o tema ariya e atela nao carregava o logon grafico então aparecia uma msg assim:  Não foi encontrado o tema /user/shared/kde4/apps/kdm/themes/ariya e eu dava ok então carregava no modo texto para fazer o logon com o comando informado aqui deu certo e carregou novamente o logon grafico segue o comando que deu certo aqui para mim

sudo apt-get install --reinstall kdm

comando executado em modo texto e depois desse comando eu dei o comando shutdown -r now

quando reiniciou o pc voltou o logon da tela grafica valeu pela dica.